# Resolving conflicts between two proposed state transitions

Tags: consensus

Given a state object `S` and two proposed actions `a` and `b`, and a reducer function that applies actions such that `f(S, x) => S'`, is it reasonable to assume that `a` and `b` do not collide if `f(f(S, a),b) = f(f(S,b), a)`?

For a bit of context to this question: I'm working on a p2p consensus algorithm where no one peer owns the state object, but can propose actions to be performed on it. Each peer hashes the result of the operation and checks it against the provided hash in the proposal of the expected output. If the hashes match, then the peer signs the result, attaches the signature and their public key to the proposal, and forwards the proposal onto their other peers. In the event that a peer receives two proposals that collide, it will accept whichever proposal has more signatures from peers on the network, and sign it as described above. This works in most cases, except when two proposals arrive at a peer with an equal number of signatures. I don't think the peer can't ignore/reject both, as that logic would hamper propagation. I can foresee scenarios where `a` and `b` might be acceptable to apply in the same epoch, so figuring out how to accept those scenarios would save time/effort/headaches.